# batch to replace some part of text list with replacement specified in another text list

Tags: file, text, replace

I need a bat file to make a dynamic replace of some part of text

The replacement change usually i need to insert the REPLACEMENT directly in a text file saved in my pc

text files with text to replace contains row like (D:\Programmi Installati\list_to_replace.txt):

```
home.php&sid=1111111111&hid=2222222222
house.php&sid=3333333333&hid=9999999999
horse.asp&sid=4444444444&hid=2222222222
```

text files with the new sid to using with replace all old sid (D:\Programmi Installati\list_new_sid.txt):

```
9999999999
```

I need to update ALL the OLD sid with a new sid that I can specify in a text list saved in my pc

Example final replacement:

The text files (D:\Programmi Installati\list_new_sid.txt) contains the new sid like 9999999999

the bat procedeed to replacement old sid with the new sid and make this result in (D:\Programmi Installati\list_to_replace.txt)

```
home.php&sid=9999999999&hid=2222222222
house.php&sid=9999999999&hid=9999999999
horse.asp&sid=9999999999&hid=2222222222
```

This is an example row saved in the list

siteaaa.it/en/page.aspx?fqdn=name.vpn.net&ip=10.20.30.40&tcp=0&udp=20788&sid=**NE‌​WSIDTOREPLACE**&hid=8888888

it is necessary to adapt the code to replace only part between &sid= AND &hid= (i write the part in bold to identificate easly) and do not remove of edit other part of text

Can you help me please?

Thanks, Best Regards

Comment: Any idea to create this replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /P "newSid=" < "c:/programmi/list_new_sid.txt"
(for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("c:/programmi/list_to_replace.txt") do (
   set "url=%%a"
   for /F "delims==&" %%b in ("!url:*sid=!") do (
      set "url=!url:%%b=%newSid%!"
   )
   echo !url!
)) > temp.txt
move /Y temp.txt "c:/programmi/list_to_replace.txt"
```

Comment: Hi i tried your bat but need an optimization, some url after replacement lost part of url. I tested on url like "siteaaa.it/en/page.aspx?fqdn=name.vpn.net&ip=10.20.30.40&tcp=0&udp=20788&sid=9999999999&hid=8888888" and the bat removed part of url. It's necessary to make a replace only on 9999999999 (part after sid=) and not remove part before sid= and after &hid. Thanks for help

Comment: Url Before replacement "siteaaa.it/en/page.aspx?fqdn=name.vpn.net&ip=10.20.30.40&tcp=0&udp=20788&sid=99‌​99999999&hid=8888888" after replacement must "siteaaa.it/en/page.aspx?fqdn=name.vpn.net&ip=10.20.30.40&tcp=0&udp=20788&sid=NEWSID&hid=8888888"

Comment: it is necessary to adapt the code to replace only part between &sid= AND &hid= and do not remove of edit other part of text &sid=REPLACETHISONLY&hid=

Comment: Please, do this: 1. Carefully read [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6108) 2. Modify your question and include an example of _real_ url data; do NOT include new info and long explanations in comments! 3. Post a comment here as advice that you completed previous steps.

Comment: @ Aacini I thanks you, i'm not english and for me it's hard to write in english, some my word can be not perfect because i'm not english and usually i must to use translator to write (with some error). I'm happy for your support and your work to help me I added in post an url example. excuse me but i use translator to write some word and can be not perfect.

Comment: If you have not enough experience in Batch files to fix small details, then you must include _complete details_ in your questions. Why do you put a file name with no spaces in the example when the real file name have spaces? Why do you put two `&` characters in url's when the real url's have several? If you don't help us writting complete descriptions of your problems we will no longer help you to solve they! Did you read [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6108)?

Comment: The latest your script works perfect. i know very little bat script and for me it's very hard to create bat script. The file's name usually change (i have different files with different structure) and i prefer to can put the path to adapt it for every need. In next ask i add more information to solve more fast my request. Thanks again for your help, I read the page you link. Best Regards